# Display results according to Users location

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where users table has column Country,state and city. and another table named projects also contains the column country,state and city.
Now i want to get the most relevent results from project table where projects should have same city,state and country. means the row where city.state and country all match should be on top. and which only match country should be at bottom.

**users**

```
 ID  |  username  | country | state   | city 

1   |    user1   | country1| state1  |city1
2   |    user2   | country2| state2  |city2
3   |    user3   | country3| state3  |city3
```

**projects**

```
  title | country | state   | city

  p1   | country1| state1  |city1
  p2   | country1| state1  |city2
  p3   | country1| state2  |city2
```

Suppose user1 is login and i want to show most relevent results to this user according to user location.
e.g in project taqble in row p1 all country state and city mis matching with user country state and city. in p2 two only country and state is matching and in p3 only country is matching. what i want to do it to retrieve row in in this order p1,p2 and p3.

Comment: Post some sample data and desired result will be more help.

Comment: i have updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope help for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f737/13)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`ID` int, `username` varchar(5), `country` varchar(8), `state` varchar(6), `city` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`ID`, `username`, `country`, `state`, `city`)
VALUES
    (1, 'user1', 'country1', 'state1', 'city1'),
    (2, 'user2', 'country2', 'state2', 'city2'),
    (3, 'user3', 'country3', 'state3', 'city3')
;


CREATE TABLE projects
    (`title` varchar(2), `country` varchar(8), `state` varchar(6), `city` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO projects
    (`title`, `country`, `state`, `city`)
VALUES
    ('p1', 'country1', 'state1', 'city1'),
    ('p2', 'country1', 'state1', 'city2'),
    ('p3', 'country1', 'state2', 'city2')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, (t1.country = t2.country) + (t1.state = t2.state) + (t1.city = t2.city) as cnt
from users t1
left join projects t2
on t1.country = t2.country or t1.state = t2.state or t1.city = t2.city
order by t1.id, cnt desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f737/13/0)**:

```
| ID | username |  country |  state |  city |  title |  country |  state |   city |    cnt |
|----|----------|----------|--------|-------|--------|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |    user1 | country1 | state1 | city1 |     p1 | country1 | state1 |  city1 |      3 |
|  1 |    user1 | country1 | state1 | city1 |     p2 | country1 | state1 |  city2 |      2 |
|  1 |    user1 | country1 | state1 | city1 |     p3 | country1 | state2 |  city2 |      1 |
|  2 |    user2 | country2 | state2 | city2 |     p3 | country1 | state2 |  city2 |      2 |
|  2 |    user2 | country2 | state2 | city2 |     p2 | country1 | state1 |  city2 |      1 |
|  3 |    user3 | country3 | state3 | city3 | (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```